# In client/server program,the content of message read and written are not printed to screen, why does the server terminate after sending 1 message

Tags: c, linux, tcp, client-server

server:
I am opening the socket, naming it, binding it. Then calling listen on it. This is in while loop. Then accept is called. Then it forks. Then in the new process, it reads and writes data to buffer and prints to screen. But when the client and server run, the buffer is not printed and both the client and server end after 1st connection, though the message writing is in loop.Made change, initialized the buff in the client, but got a new problem-> the contents of buffer are not print to screen. I commented the while loop at listen. Now the server exits after connection, though it is in while loop. No message is printed. The bytes read by read function is always zero. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MAX 80
#define PORT 54321

int main()
{
    int sockfd, connfd, len, ret;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr, cli;
    char buff[MAX];
    int r,w;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) { 
        printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
    bzero(&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)); 

    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) != 0) {
    printf("socket bind failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n"); 

    //while(1)// commented, need to keep it and test
    {
        if(listen(sockfd,5) != 0)  {
            printf("Listen failed...\n"); 
            exit(0); 
        } 
        else
            printf("Server listening..\n"); 

        len = sizeof(cli);
    
        connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli, &len);

        if (connfd < 0) { 
            printf("server acccept failed...\n"); 
            exit(0); 
        } 
        else
            printf("server acccept the client...\n"); 

        ret = fork();

        if(ret == 0)
        {
            while(1)
            {
                n = 0;
                printf("enter string\n");
                bzero(buff, MAX);
                // copy server message in the buffer
                //while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n')
                  ;
                strcpy(buff, "Pintu");
                write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
                printf("Hi Server \n");
                sleep(5);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CLIENT:
The socket is created. the structure are filled. the server address is given. the connect is called. Then read and write are done in a loop.  But when the client and server run, the buffer is not printed and both the client and server end after 1st connection, though the message writing is in loop. Made change, initialized the buff in the client, but got a new problem-> the contents of buffer are not print to screen. I commented the while loop at listen. Now the server exits after connection, though it is in while loop. No message is printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MAX 80
#define PORT 54321



int main()
{
    int sockfd, connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in sockAddr, cli;
    char buff[MAX];
    strcpy(buff, "Sandeep");

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) { 
        printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
    bzero(&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr)); 

    sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    sockAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr)) != 0)  {
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("connected to the server..\n"); 

    while(1)
    {
         bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
         r = read(sockfd, buff, 3);
         printf("r = %d\n",r);
         if(r==-1) strerror(errno);
         printf("Hello %s\n",buff);
         sleep(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: `write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));` The `buff` array is uninitalised. So you are writing junk on one side and printing it as a string on the other which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: made change, initialized the buff in the client, but got a new problem-> the contents of buffer are not print to screen

Comment: For stream based protocols like TCP each `read` is not guaranteed to receive the same amount of data as a single `write`. For that reason and for best practice error checking, the return value of `read` (and other functions) needs to be checked and the string should only be printed once it's certain that it has been fully received.

Comment: I commented the while loop at listen. Now the server exits after connection, though it is in while loop. No message is printed.

Comment: You are completely ignoring the result returned by `read()`. It can be (1) -1 indicating an error, (2) zero indicating end of stream, or (3) a positive byte count indicating the number of bytes transferred into your buffer. You are also ignoring the actual error code any time you get an error. You should print `errno` or `strerr(errno)`, or call `perror()`, before calling anything else that could disturb `errno`.

Comment: always read returns zero. why what should I do?I have changed my code. see.

Comment: why read returns zero always? Is it because I am using gio mobile's wifi network?

Comment: You have changed your code without addressing a single one of the matters I raised. For example I told you to *print* `strerror(errno)`, and to do so on *any* error, not just at one site. If you get end of stream on a socket, or any error other than EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK, you have no option but to close it. And to use the byte count properly you need e.g. `printf("Hello %.*s\n", count, buff);`

Comment: i did not understand how to handle? Read is returning 0 bytes, so I have to close the socket and start again? Then how my error will be resolved? I have launched the code multiple times by restarting it.

Comment: Yes. End of stream on a socket means that the peer has closed the connection. Nothing else you can do but close yours.

Comment: .1st I want to print the string. So that I can proceed forward. No string is printed? what to do? I tried multiple times. Why this is happening?

Comment: Why are you writing to sockfd when the client is on connfd?

Comment: You can't print a string that you haven't received, and you haven't received a string because you got end of stream instead, and the reason for that is that you didn't send anything, and the reason for that is that you got an error on `write()` which you didn't detect, and the reason for that is that you're ignoring errors on `write()`, just as on `read()`.